# Change the properties of a powerpoint object

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have the following code:

```
Sub WriteTextBox()

Dim i As Integer
Dim pptcount As Integer

Dim tb As Shape
Dim sld As Slide
Dim pres As Presentation
Dim var1 As String
var1 = InputBox("Vul hier de maand in")
var2 = "Maand: "
var3 = var2 + var1

pptcount = Application.Presentations.Count

For i = 1 To pptcount
    Set pres = Application.Presentations(i)

    Set sld = pres.Slides(1)

    Set tb = sld.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 600, 50, 100, 50)
    tb.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = var3
    tb.Line.Visible = True


Next
End Sub
```

Through which I can place a new text shape into my powerpoint file. I also want to change other stuff in the object (like the font size), but when enter:

```
tb.TextFrame.TextEffect.FontBold = true
```

I get an error.

Anybody know how I can add extra features to my text box? Also tried to use `With` and `End With` statements but then it does not recognize my object:

```
With tb.TextFrame.TextRange
    .TextEffect.FontBold = true
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tb.TextFrame` has no `TextEffect` property . Try this instead:

```
tb.TextEffect.FontBold = msoTrue
```

**EDIT**
Above works in PowerPoint 2010.

The following is for PowerPoint 2003:

```
tb.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Bold = msoTrue
```

Comment: I tried it but get this error: http://www.flickr.com/photos/112983354@N05/12303399923/

Comment: It works for me in PPT 2010 - what version of PowerPoint are you running?

Comment: OK, I'll try it in PPT2003 later.

Comment: OK, no problem. You can close the question by clicking the checkmark beside the answer and with an upvote if you thought it was helpful. ;)